# C/C++ Library or example code for DSP Using the TI-MSP430

Tags: c++, audio, signal-processing

I am working on a little dsp project doing audio processing (e.g., Nyquist rate sampling, over- and undersampling, reconstruction) that is real-time embedded using my board. The current board/chip I am using is the msp430 series from Texas Instruments.

MSP430F5438 Experimenter Board <-- ( Among recommendation )
http://focus.ti.com/docs/toolsw/folders/print/msp-exp430f5438.html

First of all would you recommend buying a copy of matlab or octave as my main coding tool. I am using the CCS ( Code composer studio) from Texas Instruments of which came with my board.

Second is there any DSP (Open source) Library's for c/c++ that I can use for my project.

Comment: Note that Octave is free.  And free is a very good price...

Comment: TI makes DSP chips (good ones too), but the MSP430 isn't one of them.  It's a very low-power microcontroller with much lower performance than a DSP.  No floating-point hardware and no integer division (multiplication is supported).  You can use an ADC -> MSP430 -> DAC, but you likely won't be happy with the complexity of real-time processing you can fit in.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C/C++ Library or example code for DSP Using the TI-MSP430](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523943/c-c-library-or-example-code-for-dsp-using-the-ti-msp430)

Comment: TI makes DSP chips (good ones too), but the MSP430 isn't one of them. It's a very low-power microcontroller with much lower performance than a DSP. No floating-point hardware and no integer division (multiplication is supported). You can use an ADC -> MSP430 -> DAC, but you likely won't be happy with the complexity of real-time processing you can fit in.

Comment: If you knew anything about C or C++, you would not use the term "script", neither are scripting languages.  TI provide ample support libraries and examples.

Comment: So, what would i have to do to make a simple audio dsp process using the board?

Answer (score 1):

I think Matlab may be useful for getting algorithms down "on paper" without having to worry about hardware. It's also useful for the various DSP functions that you may want to try (which either come with Matlab or are available as a package/toolbox). However, a function that you get "for free" in Matlab would need to be rewritten if it doesn't exist in a C/C++ library.

Also you will eventually need to get the code into the MSP - I've used CCS in the past, as well as, [IAR Systems](http://www.iar.com/website1/1.0.1.0/220/1/) which I was very happy with.

For your second question, check out answers to this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1761212/404469) which asks the same thing. One link that looks promising is this one: http://spuc.sourceforge.net/.

Answer (score 1):

Your board should have come with code examples. According to the page you linked to above, it comes with [MSP430F54xx Code Examples (Rev. O) (zip 525 KB)](http://www.ti.com/litv/zip/slac166o). Did you try any of these examples ?

Comment: Yes, however none of them are dsp related examples. They deal with other functions of the board like the accelerometers.

Comment: Maybe consider using a DSP evaluation board rather than a micro controller ? These typically have 16 bit ADCs and DACs and come with sample code for various audio DSP operations.

Answer (score 0):

In general, using a high-level language for algorithmic development is a great idea.  I've heard, though don't know for sure, that Code Composer Studio has integration with MATLAB to the extent that you can run MATLAB code right on your target.  If

- this is true,
- you have the budget for it, and
- you're not trying to wring every last gram of performance from the chip,

then this is definitely a great feature.  Otherwise, Octave is a very good alternative.  It is sometimes slower than MATLAB, and doesn't have some of the more exotic toolboxes, but for prototyping and learning it's perfectly suitable and FREE.

Recently I've been using Python with NumPy for prototyping, and I'm very happy with it.  You might consider this rather than MATLAB/Octave, especially if you're coming from C++.  The language is easy to work with, unlike MATLAB, and the NumPy (and sometimes SciPy) extension libraries provide a lot of the same basic functionality.  It is also easy to call C libraries from Python, providing an easy way to port pieces of your high-level stuff into C iteratively.

As for libraries, I've also heard good things about [SPUC](http://spuc.sourceforge.net/), which [gary comtois](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523943/c-c-library-or-example-code-for-dsp-using-the-ti-msp430/4524081#4524081) recommended.  I haven't worked with a TI chip in a while, but they used to provide some of the building blocks like `sin`, `cos`, `FFT`, and `biquad` in various application notes or even as a linkable library.

Answer (score 0):

The MSP430 isn't a specialist DSP processor. However, that doesn't (necessarily) mean you can't process audio with it, but it may not be straightforward.

I'd probably try and set up a timer interrupt at the required audio sampling frequency which reads a sample from the ADC, does something to it, and outputs it to the audio DAC.

You only have a 12-bit ADC, so don't expect miracles or CD-quality audio.

```
void my12KHzTimer()
{
  writeDAC(readADC() / 2); // DSP loop to reduce volume by 6 dB
}
```

writeDAC and readADC are assumed to do what they say on the tin...